# Android Navigation component: Is there any way I can change selected tab of BottomNavigation programmatically

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I am using the Android Jetpack Navigation component. My code has 3 tabs and a BottomNavigationView that is following [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) of google.

[image] [image]

Is there any way that I can change the tab from Home->Leaderboard when I clicking on the About button like when I perform click to Leaderboard on BottomNavigationView?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @HenryTwist oh yes! That is exactly what I am looking for! But how can I pass some arguments to the second tab when I clicking on the About button?

Comment: Glad it helped! Make sure in future you research your questions. That was the first result when I searched the exact title of *this question*. In regards to arguments, if you're using the navigation component there's plenty of tutorials etc out there that should cover that, otherwise if you're stuck on a particular point you can ask another question.

Comment: I have exactly the same question as the original poster: with the Navigation component, how do I change to another BottomNavigation tab programmatically? I fail to find the answer in the linked post.