# Switch tab on button click with Bottom Navigation and Navigation component

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-bottomnav

I have a very simple app that consists of three Fragments and a Bottom Navigation bar, created by using "New Project -> Bottom Navigation Activity" in Android Studio. The first Fragment holds a button, which should take me to the second Fragment, like if the middle button of the Bottom Navigation bar was clicked.

[image: Fragment with Button]

Is there a "standard" way to do this?

I have tried:

- using `launch(...)` of the Navigation component, which seems to launch the Fragment with its own back stack and breaks the bottom navigation.
- using `setSelectedItemId(...)` in different ways, which either results in an exception or breaks bottom navigation in different ways.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68149447/android-navigation-component-is-there-any-way-i-can-change-selected-tab-of-bott), someone asks the exact same question, but it is marked as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202294/set-selected-item-in-android-bottomnavigationview). I fail to find the answer, especially concerning Navigation component.

Comment: What have you got on implementing the solutions in the mentioned question?

Comment: Depending on how and which, an Exception or an non-working Bottom Navigation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clicking the `Button` should have the same effect as if the user taps the corresponding item in the bottom navigation. So you need to call [setSelectedItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView#setSelectedItemId(int)) on the `BottomNavigationView`. This can only be done in the `Activity` displaying the `BottomNavigationView`.

One option is to introduce a [shared `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) with

- a `LiveData` to be observed by the `Activity`
- a function `onButtonClicked()` to be called by the `OnClickListener` of your `Button` which will update the `LiveData`

Once the `LiveData` observer fires, your `Activity` can call

```
 binding.navView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_dashboard
```

Please note that for passing information about events like this one should choose some data type which can be invalidated after use. See for example [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)

Comment: This works and is written very well :) Btw: there is now official documentation about [passing events via LiveData](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide/ui-layer/events). I do find the medium article easier to read and understand though.

Comment: How can I handle data passing here?

Comment: @Sumit Shukla - please ask a new question to better describe your requirement :)

Answer (score -2):

Paste this code from where you want to go to the second fragment

```
Fragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).commit();
```

For more information [click here](https://codinghubexpress.blogspot.com/2022/03/bottomnavigationview-android-example.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The title of the question and the question itself asks about changing a tab programmatically with Bottom Navigation and the [Android Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started). How does this answer solve that question?